# Summing all entries in a csv that contain all or portion of a string

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, numpy

Right now I'm trying to sum the number of entries that fall within a given date range of an arbitrary column in this (subarray) of a csv (there are 3 date columns in total and I want to be able to look at any column and there respective entries):
(label:id,Label:invoice number, Label appt date, Label completion date, label: invoice amount last appointment date)

```
(label 1,  Label 2,    Label 3,            label 4,         label 5, label 6)
18565272,  3548587,    2015-12-30 16:30:00, 2017-01-18 4:01:00,  0,  11/30/2016
22909611,  2000404134, 2016-05-18 14:55:00, 2017-01-26 16:59:00, 0,  NULL
21541501,  1166588,    2016-07-07 17:00:00, 2017-02-14 4:01:00,  84, 4/11/2016
1000141115,1429670,    2016-10-29 0:06:00,  2017-01-18 21:43:00, 49, 3/2/2016
```

I'd like to be able to define a column and then compute the number of times a date appears that lie within a range-say "January 1-30 2016".  I'm not really experienced with methods related to this (most of my python experience is in the numerical computation side).  I have a few ideas at present (using pandas to remove rows that do not contain a given entry along the row and then summing the row count for instance) but I'm looking for a few that probably work a lot better.

Comment: The data doesn't seem to make sense, or maybe you could explain the columns. I see three dates, two with times and then 3 other columns. If it is just one of the date columns that needs to be checked to be within a range then slicing will be quite easy, but a smaller, more clear set of example data would help.

Comment: Right!  so there are labels for each column i just added in, sorry about that.  the first two columns are just id numbers, but the first date is the apptment date, the second date is the completion date, the number following is the invoice number, and the last date was the last time they showed up.

So basically, depending on which column i want to consider-I'd like to disclaim a range and find how many dates in that column fall in there!

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(your_file) # read the data

def date_range_counter(column, start_date, end_date)
    dates_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date) # creates list of dates between start_date and end_date
    arr = df[df[column].isin(dates_range)] # will only keep rows of the dataframe that have dates in the range specified
    return len(arr)
```

for start_date and end_date you can use strings in the format 'YYYY/MM/DD' and the column input should be a string of the column label you want to count dates from e.g 'Label 1'.

Comment: Thanks!  Will try now!

Comment: Let me know how it goes!